# Show/hide fields (if empty --> don't show)

Tags: google-docs, automation, zapier

we are working on a project to atomize our offer process. We have multiple insurance products which can be chosen and are then passed on through zapier to Google Docs. Obviously not every customer needs all the products so I want to hide fields in the doc when no data is passed on. See example in yellow. This doc is produced automatically and the yellow data point is missing. I would like to empty this part/input and then all the other data is moving up.

Anybody has some ideas? WebMerge can do that: https://support.webmerge.me/hc/en-us/articles/206526076-Conditional-Sections --> if empty

All help very much appreciated.

[image]

Hey Cornelius, sorry to be inprecise.

*italic*" And you're trying to avoid having template variables left over when you didn't specify a value to replace them with. Can you confirm that this interpretation is correct?" --> Yes!*italic*

So If something is entered the currently the placeholders still appear - but they shouldn't!

Comment: You probably mean automize not atomize ;) It would help to have more context on what you're trying to achieve. Do you want us to give advice on how to produce the document with Zapier I presume - or do you want to have an extra step after it's produced to get rid of tags such as {{...}}? The more detail you give the better. Maybe you can share a step by step description of the current process and/or what you're trying to do in Google docs. There is probably a way to do what you want using Apps script/macro or the like. But I need more detail.

Comment: Hey - yeah I meant automize sorry; more the second ("- or do you want to have an extra step after it's produced to get rid of tags such as {{...}}?) - I have the placeholders in my google docs but I will have cases when the data is simply empty; in those cases I would like to empty the placeholders in google docs and the simply show the rest auf the data;

Comment: Step: 1 --> get data from Hubspot form
Step: 2 --> Create a doc from google docs template and produce sheet above
Step: 3 --> have a finished offer where I pass back the link to Hubspot

In Step 1: I have conditional fields meaning some if them won't be filled; but so since I have to map all the fields to pass it on to the google docs placeholders
In Step 2: I have a template and want to produce the document from it; but when data is missing - which you can see in yellow - the placeholders are still there - this part should be empty and all other data should move up

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for adding detail. Please edit it into the question as opposed to commenting :)

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand what you're looking for. You're requiring help with ZAPIER for the App: Google Docs, specifically the activity "Create Document from Template". And you're trying to avoid having template variables left over when you didn't specify a value to replace them with.

Can you confirm that this interpretation is correct? The way you ask the question unfortunately doesn't make it obvious. It would help if you rewrote the question to make it clearer what you're looking for. https://zapier.com/apps/google-docs/tutorials/create-autopopulate-google-docs-template

Comment: Hey Cornelius, sorry to be inprecise. " And you're trying to avoid having template variables left over when you didn't specify a value to replace them with. Can you confirm that this interpretation is correct?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Zapier replaces the tag with an empty string. So try to make Hubspot pass at least something along, like a space if an empty string isn't possible.

Comment: ok understood - passing on at least something - but then I have the problem that on the google doc it shows me blank space but I want to have basically an if then branch! I need to get the dynamic part into the logic - maybe by a script in google docs Best